# Passing commands to named screen session via .sh script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm completely beginner with this, I googled some if elseif else tutorial and started to build this script. I'm trying to create a .sh script which gives me option to manage my valves sourceserver from the PHP script. This is what I have currently:

```
#!/bin/sh
# CONFIG
LOGFILE="/var/www/management/ifacelog"
NEWDATE=`TZ=GMT-3 date +%d.%m.%Y" "%H:%M:%S`
# END OF CONFIG
SCRIPTCOMMAND=$1
CSGOCOMMAND=$2
if [ $SCRIPTCOMMAND = "START" ] ; then
        echo $NEWDATE  "SERVER STARTED! connect cs.kask.fi; password gd | rcon_password tuksu" >> test
        touch lockfile
        screen -A -m -d -S csgo -L /home/csgo/server/srcds_run -game csgo -console -usercon -tickrate 128 +net_public_adr 46.246.93.192 +ip 46.246.93.192 +tv_port 27010 -maxplayers_override 11 +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 +host_worksh$
elif [ $SCRIPTCOMMAND = "RESTART" ] ; then
        echo $NEWDATE  "STOPPING THE SERVER" >> test
        echo $NEWDATE  "Passing command tv_stoprecord and waiting 10sec." >> test
        screen -S csgo -X stuff "tv_stoprecord"
        screen -S csgo -X stuff "
"
sleep 10
        echo $NEWDATE  "Passing command: quit" >> test
        screen -S csgo -X stuff "quit"
        screen -S csgo -X stuff "
"
        echo $NEWDATE  "SERVER RESTARTED!" >> test
elif [ $SCRIPTCOMMAND = "KILL" ]; then
        echo $NEWDATE  "KILLING SERVER!" >> test
        pkill srcds_run
        rm lockfile
        rm screenlog.0
elif [ $SCRIPTCOMMAND = "RCON" ]; then
        echo $NEWDATE  "REMOTE RCON! Passing value: " $2 $3 >> test
        screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff $2 $3
        screen -S csgo -X stuff "
"
elif [ $SCRIPTCOMMAND = "RESET" ]; then
        rm lockfile
        rm screenlog.0
else
        echo "UNKNOWN COMMAND WAS PASSED!"
fi
```

Everything is working except passing commands to screen session itself (If scriptcommand = RCON). If I type in shell `screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff say test`, it passes it to screen session properly. If I run my script `./csgo.sh RCON say test`, screen says error `-X: stuff: invalid option "say"`. I tried also with `screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff \"$2\"` but that didn't make any difference.

Since this works fine if I type it manually, I have no idea why it doesn't work on script. Any idea why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: usually it is a good practice put quotes around variables, e.g. `elif [ "$SCRIPTCOMMAND" = "RESET" ]; then` - because now, if the SCRIPTCOMMAND is empty the scrit will not work... (and apply this to `"$2"` and others too... maybe helps (i don't analysed the script - but it is probably some quotes error...

Comment: Put an `echo` before each screen command, and post what is printed.

Comment: @Rubens
`kask@tor:/var/www/management$ ./csgo.sh RCON say test
screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff say test`

@jm666 Quotes didn't help.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure if I actually understand what you're trying to do in the command `screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff say test`, but you may need to add some quotes, to limit what words correspond to which argument. Is each word an argument itself, or should it be something like: `screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff "say test"`?

Comment: @Rubens I want to be able to pass string to screen session. I have PHP script which calls `./csgo.sh RCON $STRING` where $string is what user has input into textbox. Reason why .sh script has $2 $3 currently is just a test, I got same results with only $2 and quotes. Screen gets the string to its session but takes $string value as a command, ie. error `invalid option "say"`. If I run script from my ssh session `./csgo.sh RCON "say test"`, it gives same error. If I copypaste that command from script `screen -X -S csgo -p 0 stuff "mp_restartgame 1"`, it works.